# Is it possible to Create sample movie ( mini movie) with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to create a mini movie ( if i have a movie which is 1 hour - i want 3 seconds of it) with ffmpeg ?

How do i do it ?

Comment: How is this a programming-related question? Use the [FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html) at http://ffmpeg.org, `man ffmpeg`, `ffmpeg --help` or Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command will copy the first 3 seconds of `input.avi` to `output.avi`.

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 3 -i input.avi -codec copy output.avi
```

This will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux), so no encoding is occurring.

If you want to re-encode then remove `-codec copy`:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 3 -i input.avi output.flv
```

Comment: Just use `output.flv`. Ffmpeg converts files according to the extension, provided that the codec is supported.